# Failed to close the popup modal form in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, requirejs, modal-popup

**I have created  Popup modal form, the form is successfully submitted and showing response, but after showing response I need to close the popup modal but failed to close the popuup modal**

**js file**

```
 define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal"

],
        function ($) {
            "use strict";
            // Review form 
            var xxx = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: false,
                title: "aaa",
                modalClass: "popup-center",
                clickableOverlay: true,

            };
           var abc = $('#form-div-id').modal(xxx);
            $(".link").click(function () {
                abc.modal("openModal");
            });

            return function (config) {
                $('#review-form').on("click", "#review-submit", function () {
                    var form_data = $("#review-form").serialize();
                    var reviewurl = config.url;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: reviewurl,
                        type: 'POST',
                        // Pass the submitted form data to Controller
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function (response) {

                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            if (returnedData.status === 'success')
                                $("#success").html(returnedData.messages);
                            else
                                $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);


                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                        }

                    });
                    var close = this;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        close.closeModal();
                    }, 3000);
                   return false;

                });
            };

        });
```

Comment: Have you got an error in your console ?
How do you open the modal ?

Comment: could you paste code inside success function setTimeout(function () {
            close.closeModal();
        }, 3000)

Comment: Am I need to place inside success, after the else part  ??

Comment: see the updated post @Vinz

Comment: yes inside success function after else part

Comment: I've just seen, you have a return false before the close. The close should be before it.

Comment: I hope [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174782/magento-2-js-modal-popup-close-event) will help you.

Comment: See the updated post I have placed false before close modal but still it is failed to close popup @Vinz

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have used this:

> var close = this;

Where 'this' will represent $('#review-form') object. While you have initiated modal for $('#form-div-id'). So This is the reason that's why modal is not closing, closeModal method belongs to modal($('#form-div-id')) object not form object.

Please use model like this:

1. Initialize model like

> define([ "jquery", "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal",  "jquery/ui"],
>
> function ($,modal) {

2. Assign to Dom elements like this:

> var abc = modal(xxx, $('#form-div-id'));

Where xxx is modal options.

3. And call modal open and close like this:

> abc.openModal();

And closing

> abc.closeModal();

Please note:

> close modal should be called before return of function please use alert method to put before close modal and debug is alert is coming or not while closing.

Comment: I have tried as you said but popup is failed to open

Comment: @Kumar M , You saved my day. :) it works.Nice explanation, U appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**just add condition in success section like below:**

```
 define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal"

],
        function ($) {
            "use strict";
            // Review form 
            var xxx = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: false,
                title: "aaa",
                modalClass: "popup-center",
                clickableOverlay: true,

            };
           var abc = $('#form-div-id').modal(xxx);
            $(".link").click(function () {
                abc.modal("openModal");
            });

            return function (config) {
                $('#review-form').on("click", "#review-submit", function () {
                    var form_data = $("#review-form").serialize();
                    var reviewurl = config.url;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: reviewurl,
                        type: 'POST',
                        // Pass the submitted form data to Controller
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function (response) {

                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            if (returnedData.status === 'success')
                                $("#success").html(returnedData.messages);
                              //to close form
                              $('#review-form').modal('closeModal');
                            else
                                $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);


                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                        }

                    });
                    var close = this;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        close.closeModal();
                    }, 3000);
                   return false;

                });
            };

        });
```

Hope, this will help you some extend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var abc = $('#form-div-id').modal(productreview);
            $(".link").click(function () {
                abc.modal("openModal");
            });
    return function (config) {
        $('#review-form').on("click", "#review-submit", function () {
            var form_data = $("#review-form").serialize();
            var reviewurl = config.url;
            $.ajax({
                url: reviewurl,
                type: 'POST',
                // Pass the submitted form data to Controller
                data: form_data,
                success: function (response) {

                    var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                    if (returnedData.status === 'success')
                        $("#success").html(returnedData.messages);
                    else
                        $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                    $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                }
            });
            //But failed to close
            var close = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                close.closeModal();
            }, 3000);
            return false;
        });

    };
```

**You have set closemodel() function after function return false so your call is not executing.**

You need to set return false at last in your js.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have done as you said , but popup failed to close,  See the updated post