# Add button to admin grid magento 2

Tags: magento2, template, grid

How can I add a button in the Adminhtml `Reports>>Sales>>Orders`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to ovveride this file

> \vendor\magento\module-backend\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\grid\extended.phtml

and I wanted to be added after line 41 to be added to this class `admin__data-grid-export`

And it could be done in a way mentioned [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/128203/59293)

And i edited the code to not be a link but a button:

```
<button type="button" name="submit" id=click-me  style="margin:0 20px" >Testing</button> 
    <div id="popup-mpdal" style="display:none;">
        <h1> POPUP TEXT </h1>
        <input type="text">
    </div>

    <script>
        require(
            [
                'jquery',
                'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
            ],
            function(
                $,
                modal
            ) {
                var options = {
                    type: 'popup',
                    responsive: true,
                    innerScroll: true,
                    title: 'popup mpdal title',
                    buttons: [{
                        text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                        class: '',
                        click: function () {
                            this.closeModal();
                        }
                    }]
                };

                var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));
                $("#click-me").on('click',function(){ 
                    $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
                });

            }
        );
    </script>
```