# Create pop-up on click on menu category

Tags: magento2, menu, popup

I want to create a popup message when the customers click on one of menu item and also when they click on OK in popup message I want to display the message on the clicked menu category page. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/128203/3368

Comment: Where should I deploy the code for the popup to appear on click on menu item