# Open popup onClick of anchor tag

Tags: magento2

I need to open a popup on click of anchor link. I followed this ([How to open popup when <a> tag onClick?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128199/how-to-open-popup-when-a-tag-onclick)) answer but the issue is that i have to add script inside .phtml file.

I want to include the script in .js file and then use it. How can i achieve this?

I have already tried by adding inside Vendor/Theme/web/js/custom.js but then the pop up is not getting displayed.

The second solution in the ([How to open popup when <a> tag onClick?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128199/how-to-open-popup-when-a-tag-onclick)) link is not working for me.

Can some guide me towards this?

Comment: i hope you have checked my answer

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following to show popup:

```
<div class="view-popup"  onclick="show_popup()">
    <span>click to view popup</span>
</div>
```

whatever you want to show in popup,

```
<div id="popup-wrapper" style="display:none;" >
    <div class="popup-content">
        popup content popup content
    </div>
</div>
```

Add below popup script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "jquery",
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
        'mage/storage',
        "jquery/ui",
        "jquery/validate",
        "mage/translate",
        "mage/mage"

    ], function ($, confirm, storage) {
        window.show_popup = function () {
            var options1 = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                clickableOverlay: false,
                title: 'Size Chart',
                buttons: [{

                }]
            };
            $("#popup-wrapper").show();
            $("#popup-wrapper").modal(options1).modal('openModal');
        }
    });
</script>
```

You can use Anchor tag instead of span.

clear the cache and check..